# Define dynamic struct

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct, definition

I want to define a structure with different variable type in some field. for example i define a struct like this:

```
struct sensor {
  int index;
  int value;
};

struct sensor2 {
  int index;
  float value; 
};
```

i want to declare only one structure with two option, someone integer value and other time float value, but in unique structure. 
My question is : 
1.there are anyway to declare one structure and pass parameter to chose one of type (int or float or ...)?
2. can i use template for this reason?

```
struct sensor {
  int index;
  type_as_option value; //int or float
};
```

thank for your aid with best regard

Comment: `bool is_float; int int_value; float float_value;`?

Comment: You could use an anonymous `union` within the `struct`: `struct sensor { int index; union { int v; float t; } };` since a `union` can contain only one of the data members and uses only enough memory to store the largest of it's members. This allows you to choose between the two in your specific case without resorting to templates. If this is sufficient, I'll move it to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. You could make it a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct sensor {
    int index;
    T value;
};
```

However, if you want the two structs being the same type, this is not what you are looking for, as

```
sensor<int>
```

and

```
sensor<float>
```

are two different types.

Second option is (as immibis pointed out in a comment) to simply make a struct with both

```
struct sensor {
    int index;
    int ivalue;
    float fvalue;
};
```

However, this introduces almost 50% memory overhead that can be avoided by using a union:

```
union intOrFloat {
    int ivalue;
    float fvalue;
};

struct sensor {
    int index;
    intOrFlaot value;
};
```

Of the union always only one field is active and it doesnt use more memory than necessary.

Comment: There are any way to declare  template <typename T> with fix length? for example if my variable is float set 4 byte length and when is uint8_t set 1 byte for data and 3 byte free space?

Comment: I want to set all struct variable in same memory size!